# R - different colors for histo-like lines in a plot based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, colors

I have a data.frame that looks like this (df)

```
    mean      t value
    0.004      3.12
    0.021      3.41 
      .         .
      .         .
   -0.067     -3.60
```

My actual data.frame has 90 columns (90 means and 90 t values)

now i plotted the values from the first column (means)

```
mean<-df$mean
timestamp<-seq(from=-30, to=60)
plot(mean~timestamp, type="h", lwd=2, col="darkgrey", main="test")
```

the result looks like this

[image]

Now i would like to have my plotlines in a different color dependent on the t values from the second column.

For Example: If the t value is >2 or <-2 than the ploted mean line should be black and if the t values is between -2 and 2 it should be grey

I hope that there is a way to do it ;)
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job. Just have to identify the data that meets your condition and then add it with `lines`

```
df = data.frame(mean = rnorm(91), tvalue = rnorm(91,4,1.5))
mean<-df$mean
timestamp<-seq(from=-30, to=60)
t_pos = t_neg = mean
t_pos[df$tvalue< -2 & df$tvalue >2] = NA
t_neg[df$tvalue> -2 & df$tvalue < 2] = NA
plot(mean~timestamp, type="h", lwd=2, col="darkgrey", main="test")
lines(timestamp,t_pos,col="darkgrey", type = "h")
lines(timestamp,t_neg,col="black", type ="h")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another column in `df` that specifies a color based on `tvalue`. Then you can specify this column in the `col` argument of `plot`.

```
df$cols <- ifelse(df$tvalue < -2 | df$tvalue > 2, "black", "gray")
with(df, plot(mean~timestamp, type="h", lwd=2, col=cols, main="test"))
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(510)
df <- data.frame(mean = sample(seq(-0.1, 0.2, length.out = 91), 91), 
                 tvalue = sample(seq(-3, 3, length.out = 91), 91))
df$timestamp <- seq(from=-30, to=60)
```

[image]